# Zuul Configurations in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to figure out how to configure below 2 values if I have an application with 1.6 millions user and with 25 zuul instances, any recommendations? also do I need to change anything else in spring-boot config for tomcat, I'm also using ribbon as well. thank you!

zuul.host.max-total-connections=1000

zuul.host.max-per-route-connections=100

*****Update******

Number of requests per second: 3k/sec.
Number of concurrent users : 5k.

zuul 1.4.3.RELEASE
Spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to help. How many concurrent users? How many requests per second? Have you tried these values? Are you seeing errors? What versions are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb, thank you for picking up my question I have updated the question to answer your questions, thanks in advance!

Comment: you answered some of them. Have you tried these values? Are you seeing errors?

Comment: Hi @spencergibb, I don't see any errors but I'm trying to come up with recommended numbers for such load, may you please explain when I should increase each one of the properties?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm comfortable making a recommendation based on a few metrics. My advice is to monitor and adjust as you see changes.

Comment: Thank you again, with the belo config I'm getting timeout for some requests and 'request was aborted' for others.

zuul.host.max-total-connections=1000

zuul.host.max-per-route-connections=100

zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=100000

server.tomcat.max-connections=1000

server.tomcat.max-threads=1000